# Confusing antenna datasheet (feed points)

Tags: antenna, gps

I'm looking at the TDK ANT016008LCD1575MA1 for a GPS application. It has two pads for radiator electrodes (which is for tuning/matching capacitors).
But it's confusing about the four feed points. It says 2, 3, 5 and 6 are internally connected. Can I connect two separate signals to the antenna (2+3 for GPS signal and 5+6 for BT or similar 2.4GHz signal? Or do I have one path to 2+3+5+6 and RF switch it into the proper BT or GPS port?

[Datasheet](https://product.tdk.com/en/system/files?file=dam/doc/product/rf/rf/antenna/catalog/rf_ant_ant016008lcd1575ma1_summary_en.pdf)

Comment: As I understand, in the suggested layout the common feed point for both frequencies is on the left end of the horizontal track. This track is common for both bands and then the antenna splits the signal into two different vertical paths to match the impedance of each band. All 4 pins together are just one electrical connection.

Answer (score 0):

They're connected internally, so yes but not at the same time  basically the same as if all four are connected outside the part.

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. Should I use an RF switch to select GPS or BT, then connect the RF switch out to all four feed points? Or do I connect GPS to 2+3 and BT to 5+6?